# Is there an equivalent --mtime option for bsdtar?

Tags: linux, tar, bsdtar

I need to use bsdtar to create an archive and set the modification time the same way as I would do with tar (with --mtime=date option), but I cannot find any equivalent option for bsdtar.
I need to use bsdtar because with tar I have issues with extended attributes.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't absolutely have to do this as an argument passed to bsdtar, you can change any file's mtime with touch (requires root privileges): `touch -d "<time>" <filename>`.

See https://askubuntu.com/questions/62492/how-can-i-change-the-date-modified-created-of-a-file

Otherwise this seems to be impossible to do in the exact way you described.